# Openpyxl installation in Google.colab

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to run a excel dataframe upload, however I get the following error. I've tried uploading openpyxl but the only version install is 2.5.9 but it says 3.0.0 is required to run pd.read_excel. Any suggestions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XYVZ.png)

Comment: `pip install openpyxl==3.0.9` to "upgrade" your version of openpyxl

Comment: Also please include code and tracebacks as formatted code, not linked images. If the links break, the information goes missing

Answer (score 1):

in code section, run `pip install openpyxl==3.0.9` once.
then restart runtime ***Ctrl + M***

Comment: In my case it is already slower to read .xlsx file .